# set line width to radial gradient

Tags: ios, core-graphics, radial-gradients

I am using radial gradient to draw circle. It is working fine but now I want to set border color and border width to that. I tried it but it was not working.

Here is my code,

```
CGGradientRef gradient;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
CGFloat locations[] = {0.0,1.0};
CGFloat components[] = { red2,green2,blue2,1.0,red1,green1,blue1,1.0  };
colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace,components,locations,
                                               sizeof(locations)/sizeof(CGFloat));

CGPoint start = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2 ), end = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2 , self.bounds.size.height/2);
CGFloat startRadius = 0.0, endRadius = radius;
CGContextDrawRadialGradient(contextRef,gradient,start,startRadius,end,endRadius,0);
CGContextSetLineWidth(contextRef, 5.0);
CGGradientRelease(gradient);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
```

How can I set border color and width to it?

Answer (score 0):

First add `QuartzCore` Framework and then try this code...

```
[[Firstbtn layer]setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor]CGColor]];
    [[self.Firstbtn layer]setBorderWidth:2.3];
    [[self.Firstbtn layer]setCornerRadius:15];
```

Comment: is there no way to do with cgcontextref?